# Spring Boot JsonDoc configuration, http://localhost:8080/jsondoc not getting document

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jsondoc

I have a problem with configuration JsonDoc in my Spring Boot project. 
The jsondoc-ui.html is not detected.
When i enter http://localhost:8080/jsondoc I am receiving blank object like:

```
{"version":null,
 "basePath":null,
  "apis":{},
 "objects":{},
  "flows":{},
  "global":null,
 "playgroundEnabled":true,
  "displayMethodAs":"URI"}
```

Here is my configuration:

application.properties

```
jsondoc.version=1.0
jsondoc.basePath=http://localhost:8080
jsondoc.packages[0]=controller
jsondoc.packages[1]=domain
####optional configuration
jsondoc.playgroundEnabled=false
jsondoc.displayMethodAs=URI
```

my pom.xml

```
<!--JSON DOC-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jsondoc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsondoc-ui-webjar</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

and use annotaion @EnableJSONDoc in my configuration class

Comment: UPDATE: I've noticed that when i remove my application.properties configuration for application.properties the situation is the same. So it cannot detect any configuration of mine

Comment: Check your application.properties. See if it's in the correct location.